# Using EFCore to represent and store Value Objects without using Owned Types

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, .net-6.0, value-objects

My Entity currently has a property that *should* be a Value Object, but I don't know how to implement it. I am using .NET6 with EFCore and am using Entity mapping / configuration (i.e. code first).

Value Objects should not have IDs, but it will need a primary key to be stored in the database and I don't think that primary key should be the Value Object's value. Let me explain:

```
public class Race {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public Athlete AthleteA { get; set; }
    public Athlete AthleteB { get; set; }

    public RaceType RaceType { get; set; } // should be a value object
}

public class RaceType {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } // this ID probably shouldn't be there
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

RaceType may be something like "sprint" or "marathon", for example.

In .NET's documentation, it recommends making the Value Object a `record` instead of a `class` and making it an "owned type". However, there is a problem with this that I see. From their docs, the limitations of an "owned type" are:

- You can't create a DbSet of an owned type (by design).
- You can't call ModelBuilder.Entity() on owned types (currently by design).

My understanding is that I will have no ability to add new races directly, i.e. if I want to display a list of `RaceType`s on an admin page and let the admin add new values to it. This can only be done by adding a new `Race` with that new `RaceType`. Is this correct?

**What I want to do:**

I feel what I need is the ability to remove the `RaceType.Id` property from the domain model and add it to the entity configuration so that EFCore knows how to store it (i.e. in `dbo.RaceType` and a foreign key in `dbo.Race.FK_RaceType`) without the domain model having any idea that it has an ID. However, I can see no way to do this.

Is it possible to achieve this? Is there a better way to represent Value Objects in EFCore such that they get their own DB table that can be modified directly rather than having to go through an owner?

Answer (score 1):

You're question is for *.NET 6*, so I don't know how helpful this is.

In **.NET 8 / EF Core 8** you can use complex type to handle value objects.
See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-rc1/

This will **not** create a separate dbSet:

> Complex type objects:
> ...
> Must be defined as part of an entity type. (In other words, you cannot have a DbSet of a complex type.)
> ...

Value objects do not need a separate db set.

So, yeah. The EF Core 8 guideline is to use Complex types.